# P Value query, Independent t-test

Tags: t-test, p-value

Any help is much appreciated!! 
Im just querying some p values generated in SPSS from some data i have recently collected. The three groups were type 1 diabetes, type 2 diabetes and both together (type 1 and 2). 
Independent t tests were used to analyse depression (normal/ abnormal), fatigue (none/ severe) in relation to sedentary behavior. E.g is higher depression associated with increased sitting time.
After collecting data for each group, i have come up with this data:

**DEPRESSION:**  Type 1= *0.039* , Type 2= *0.05* ,  Type 1 and 2= *<0.01*

**FATIGUE**      Type 1= *0.122*  ,  Type 2= *0.012* ,    Type 1 and 2= *<0.01*

My question is how can the both group (type 1 and 2) be highly statistically significant if the other groups aren't? Does this look correct?
Thank you!!

Comment: The p-values for depression and fatigue for type 1 and type 2 diabetes were significant or nearly significant. When you combine the two types you get a larger sample size and hence the p-value could easily go further down.

Comment: "Independent t tests were used to analyse depression (normal/ abnormal), fatigue (none/ severe) in relation to sedentary behavior." IT is vague. What are your hypotheses ? and objectives ? please be specific .

Answer (score 1):

an example with the same (more clear) effect:

```
        a=0   a=1    mean
b=0     11    39     25 
b=1     41    9      25
mean    26    24     25
```

Note that the mean values are very similar, $\mu_{a=0} \sim \mu_{a=1}$ and $\mu_{b=0} \sim \mu_{b=1}$, all around 25.

But the corner-cells are very different from the mean cell value 25. So if you compare 'a=1 and b=1' with 'a != 1 or b !=1' the you will find a big difference.